# Basic Importing Excel Documents Into Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm a new Python user and am simply trying to export an Excel (or CSV) file into Jupyter Notebook to play around with.

From google searching, the common code I see is something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
```

I tried this with a CSV file and got the below error message:

> File "", line 5
>       df = pd.read_excel(C:\Users\dhauge1\Desktop\Python Workshop\fortune500.csv, sheetname=fortune500)
>                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please see above for error message. Is anyone able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change `C:\Users\dhauge1\Desktop\Python Workshop\fortune500.csv` to `r"C:\Users\dhauge1\Desktop\Python Workshop\fortune500.csv"`. Note the `r` and the `"`. For more reference search for raw string python.

Comment: According to you error you forgot quotation marks at your sheetname, if I am not mistaken. Also your error states that you are trying to read a .csv file, there is also a pd.read_csv() function.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! After a little trial and error and this help, I got it to work. I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

when reading a csv file use the comand `pd.read_csv('filename')`